# Expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`

Tags: c#

I am trying to create `Expression` for `ExpandoObject` and below is my code.

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(KeyValuePair<string, object>), "k");
var left = Expression.Property(parameter, "Key");
var right = Expression.Constant(prop, typeof(string));
var equal = Expression.Equal(left, right);
var whereMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .First(_ => _.Name == "Where").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ExpandoObject));
propExp = Expression.Call(whereMethod, propExp, equal);
```

And I am getting Exception at `Expression.Call`

> Expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`

Can someone please help?

Rishi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression expects `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` as the first parameter, just like the exception states:

> Expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' cannot be used for
>   parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`

in this line of code you are trying to convert the where linq to an Expando object:

```
var whereMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .First(_ => _.Name == "Where").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ExpandoObject));
```

But you are failing because you have an Iqueryable object:

**var whereMethod = typeof(Queryable)**

adjust the code so that the whereMethod variable be a dynamic expando object and it will work.